# Getting error : Fatal error: Call to a member function setLayer() on a non-object in

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, fatal-error

I have created the category page and created some attributes for the products but when i visit the page its giving me error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setLayer() on a non-object in /home/mxcounte/public_html/usa-tiles/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php
```

here is my **local.xml** file in following folders and link to my xml file is as follows:
/app/design/frontend/mgstheme/luxury/layout
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQ1WRjkUEDudHhDel9Va0J4OGc/view?usp=sharing

And one thing that looks suspicious as follows:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Can anyone help on this?... I am using mgstheme Luxury theme for magento.

Comment: what does it say after `Call to a member function setLayer() on a non-object in ` ?

Comment: @Marius Question is updated please check now:

Comment: indeed the xml you posted looks suspicious. Try commenting it out in your `local.xml` file and see what happens. Clear the cache when you are done.

Comment: Previously the error was on left section only but now whole page is white and showing the error:
Call to a member function setLayer() on a non-object in /home/mxcounte/public_html/usa-tiles/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php on line 134

Comment: @Marius Hey I have created categories but on front end its saying No Category Found in letf side bar, But on the main category page its showing all the categories, what is this issue:
Main Category page:http://mxcounters.com/usa-tiles/index.php/mosaics.html
Child Category with left sidebar:http://mxcounters.com/usa-tiles/index.php/mosaics/glass-mosaics.html